# Ability to write files/create directories on mounted filesystems not working in Mojave

Tags: mojave, mount, file-sharing

Recently, I upgraded to Mojave and I have discovered that filesystems to which I connect with Finder appear to have rw access, but I cannot change or create files.  Similarly with NFS mounts.  Having a file server that I cannot write to is not useful :-)

This worked prior to the upgrade, so I suspect Mojave, but I have been looking for similar issues for hours with no luck.

Any insights?

Config: Macbook Pro running Mojave 10.14.5, file server Netgear ReadyNAS OS6.10.1

Example (Finder->Go->Connect to Server->smb://fserver/pictures):

```
$ mount | grep pictures
//tarsa@fserver/pictures on /Volumes/pictures (smbfs, nodev, nosuid, mounted by tarsa)

$ ls -ld@hbefO /Volumes/pictures/
32 drwx------  1 tarsa  family  -   16K Jun  8 10:40 /Volumes/pictures//

$ touch /Volumes/pictures/foo
touch: /Volumes/pictures/foo: Permission denied
```

Example (mounting with nfs):

```
$ mount -o rw -t nfs fserver:/run/nfs4/data/Pictures ~/mnt

$ mount | grep mnt
fserver:/run/nfs4/data/Pictures on /Users/tarsa/mnt (nfs, nodev, nosuid, mounted by tarsa)

$ ls -ld@hbefO ~/mnt
3 drwxrwxr-x  1 tarsa  family  -  1.3K Jun  8 10:40 /Users/tarsa/mnt/

$ touch ~/mnt/foo
touch: /Users/tarsa/mnt/foo: Permission denied
```

Comment: In your first example you try to touch a file directly inside `/Volumes` (not on any mounted drives), is this really what you want to do? Also, can you please run `mount` and add the lines relating to your volumes to the question?

Comment: You can look at all permissions with ls -la@hbefO  Suggest you look at each directory in the path.  Add d option to force ls to give directory info as needed.

Comment: Please show the output of the 'mount' command for both of your examples,

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I have updated the examples to include the proper `touch`, `ls` for all the permissions, and provided the `mount` information.